# Bitbucket - Groovy Pre-receive Hook

Tags: groovy, bitbucket

I am trying to understand the following code snippet [following site](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/bitbucket/PostReceiveHooks.html).

```
<% refChanges.getCommits(repository).each { commit -> %>
    - ${commit.author.name} | ${commit.displayId} | ${commit.message} | ${commit.authorTimestamp}
<% } %>
```

The script is using a getCommits method, but when I look at [the documentation for the RefChange interface](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/javadoc/bitbucket-server/4.0.2/api/reference/com/atlassian/bitbucket/repository/RefChange.html) I do not see any such method.

I consider myself an expert Java developer, but I have no workable knowledge in Groovy, so I assume that I am misunderstanding Groovy or the BitBucket documentation (or both).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Groovy it's possible to add methods to a class or interface at run-time via [meta-programming](http://www.groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html). Since the `RefChange` interface does not include `getCommits()`, it must be that the method is being added after-the-fact. Based on their example code, it looks like they're using the meta-class.

### Where is getCommits()?

For example, in Groovy the `Collection` interface gets the method `findAll()` (along with many other methods). I can confirm this as follows:

```
assert Collection.metaClass.metaMethods*.name.contains('findAll') == true
```

The code above grabs the names of all the *meta methods* and then uses `contains()` to see if a match is found. You can confirm the same for `getCommits()` in a similar way:

```
assert Collection.metaClass.metaMethods*.name.contains('getCommits') == true
```

Note that I specified `Collection` rather than `RefChange` because `refChanges` is a `Collection` of `RefChange`. And so I think Atlasssian stuck `getCommits()` into `Collection` as a convenience method.

### How does it work?

To understand what's going, I'll remove the templating code:

```
refChanges.getCommits(repository).each { commit ->
    "${commit.author.name} | ${commit.displayId} | ${commit.message} | ${commit.authorTimestamp}"
}
```

1. `getCommits()` returns a `Collection` of `com.atlassian.bitbucket.commit.Commit`.
2. [Object.each(Closure)](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#each(groovy.lang.Closure)) is added by the Groovy GDK (yes, into the Object class) and it calls the `Closure` repeatedly; each time with an element of the `Collection`.
3. Although it's not apparent in the example code, the line within the `each(Closure)` is a [GString](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/groovy/lang/GString.html). Basically the expressions within the `${...}` are evaluated and the whole thing is concatenated into a `String`.

Comment: So, where would I see documentation that show getCommits methoo.

Comment: I don't know. I couldn't find it. The thing is that methods added via meta-programming do not always show up in API documentation. For instance, many (if not all) of the Groovy GDK methods are implemented as a Groovy category (see https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java). Since they are regular Java static methods (though used differently), they can be documented with JavaDoc. However, a method can also be added like this: `SomeClass.metaClass.myMethod = { name -> println "Hello, $name" }`. That would not show up in the docs.

Comment: I would expect BitBucket to document something that is expected to be used by others, but I could not find it.